# Is usage of ように appropritate in "Offer to do something"?

Tags: pragmatics

One of the options in LastPass.com is "Offer to generate a secure password". In Japanese version it is translated as "安全なパスワードを生成する**ように**提案". Is the usage of ように here delivers the meaning of "offer to do something"? Would it be more accurate to translate it as "安全なパスワードを生成することを提案する"?

Comment: I think this is like "すわるように言ってた", "She told him to sit down".  But whether you can rephrase a *suggestion* using すること I don't know.

Comment: 「安全なパスワードを生成することを提案する」="Offer generating a secure password." I think ように could sound appropriate because it could literally mean doing something in a specific way. Whether or not is is natural Japanese, I do not know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it quotes a random phrase, asks for it's correctness and ways to replace it with another one. It doesn't tell why OP thinks it might be incorrect or why it needs improvement. It doesn't quote any sources that might support either way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63922/discussion-between-karlalou-and-macraf).

Comment: 機械翻訳じゃないですかね・・・「安全なパスワードを生成するように提案（します）」って言われると、I suggest you generate a secure password みたいに聞こえるような気が…。この offer って、「（私が～することを）申し出る」（「～してあげましょうか？」みたいに）って意味ですかね？「安全なパスワードを提案します。」とか「安全なパスワードを生成します。」とかでいいような気が。。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

「ように」does not contribute to the meaning of "offer" or "propose" 「提案」. In the expression in question, the word that most closely corresponds to 「ように」is "to".

### Details

In the expression "Offer to generate a secure password"

- 「提案」translates to "Offer" or "Propose"
- 「安全なパスワード」translates to "a secure password" (included here for completeness)
- 「生成ように」translates to "(in order) to generate".

「ように」roughly means "in order to", "in order that", "in hopes that", "in the effort to", "with the goal of", etc.

「安全なパスワードを生成するように（パスワードを）提案（する）」here can be translated to "with the goal of having a secure password created, (make a) proposal (for a password)"

Answer (score 0):

In your context,

> するように
>   
> to make it a point to do (something)

is more commonly used as an instruction.

> 明日忘れずに先生に宿題を渡すように。
>   
> Tomorrow, do not forget to submit your homework to the teacher.

So to answer your question, no it can hardly be used to "offer to do something" as you are rather instructed to do so.

Bonus:

> 安全なパスワードを生成するように提案

doesn't really make any sense. If I had to correct it,

> 安全なパスワードを生成するよう、お願いいたします。
>   
>  Please generate a secure password. (in Japanese humble wording)

Answer (score 0):

> Offer to generate a secure password

I have a problem with the English word choice --  I believe this is a feature that suggests a secure password for you by generating it and presenting it to you for use. Therefore, I think the translation is not the problem here but the language source is.

Consider this: If the function generates a password then offers it to you, it should not "offer to generate a secure password" because that would semantically happen before the password is generated. What's happening here is the system suggests to the user a secure password. Therefore, it should be "Secure password suggestion". I think this is what the Japanese is translating:

> 安全なパスワードを生成するように提案

So, in your question, you are asking about the use of ように as delivering the meaning of "offering". Let's break this sentence down a bit:

> [ 安全{あんぜん｝なパスワードを生成｛せいせい｝する][ **ように** ] [ 提案｛ていあん｝ ]
>   安全なパスワード生成する = Generate a safe password 
>   **ように** = Perform by (lit. in the manner of) 
>   提案 = Suggestion

Here, **ように** is delivering the idea of "doing something in a specific manner". The phrase is not grammatically correct as a complete sentence but as a modified noun it should be generally understood, much like "Secure password suggestion" would be understood in English.